# Dialogflow bot return as unknown input for system entity values with .net integration

Tags: chatbot, dialogflow-es

I have created chat bot using Dialogflow. It integrate with .net web application through the API  according to this document.
https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-dotnet-client.

My question is whenever i passed system entity values like sys.date, sys.duration  as user input api response as unknown input and redirect to default intent. But when ever i try with dialogflow console it give correct response. Are there any issue with my side?

Comment: How are you passing input to the bot outside of the Dialogflow console?

Comment: You can pass input as request through ApiAi 
More details : https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-dotnet-client.

Comment: If you can post the code that makes the request and the response you receive, it's more likely that somebody can help you out.